# $ U(x+y) = U(x) V(y) W(y) + U(y) V(x) W(y) + U(y) V(y) W(x) + U(y) V(x) W(x) + U(x) V(y) W(x) + U(x) V(x) W(y) $

Tags: functional-equations, closed-form

Are there nonconstant solutions $U,V,W$ such that for all real $x,y$ we have

$$ U(x+y) = U(x) V(y) W(y) + U(y) V(x) W(y) + U(y) V(y) W(x) + U(y) V(x) W(x) + U(x) V(y) W(x) + U(x) V(x) W(y) $$

How to decide existance or uniqueness ?

Can we express the solutions with closed forms or differential equations ?

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Do you know that there is a closed form?

Comment: I was Just inspired by addition theorems for sin , sinh , theta functions etc. Im not aware of any nonconstant solutions. I assume exp type solution exists , but that is Just a guess. @Dando18